# How to use jQuery to compare two values?

Tags: jquery, html, compare

I'm trying to use jQuery to compare two values in an html table, and alert the user if quantity > inventory.

I want to select values in the current row :

### JS

```
    $('.item_quantity').change(function(){       
        var $this=$(this);        
        var quantity=$this.val();        
        // var inventory=$this.next('.item_inventory, td').text();
         var inventory=$(this).next('td, .item_inventory').text();

        console.log('quantity: ', quantity, 'inventory: ', inventory);
        if (quantity > inventory) {
          alert('Your order quantity ' + quantity + ' is greater than ' + inventory + ' inventory');
        }            
    });               
});
```

### HTML

```
<table >    
  <tr>         
    <td><form method=""><input class="item_quantity" type="text"  data-prodid="249" value=""/></form></td>
    <td  class="item_inventory">10</td>
    <td>Product 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>         
    <td><form method=""><input class="item_quantity" type="text" data-prodid="2" value=""/></form></td>
    <td class="item_inventory">7</td>
    <td>Product 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Changes

```
var $this=$(this);        
var quantity=$this.val();
```

to

```
var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
```

1. You don't have to instantiate `$this` to access `.val()`,
2. You have to parse the value into an int, otherwise it's a string which is returned. See below for explanations.

---

```
var inventory=$(this).next('td, .item_inventory').text();
```

to

```
var inventory = parseInt( $(this).closest('tr').find('.item_inventory').html());
```

1. `.item_inventory` is not a direct sibling of your `.item_quantity` field, so `next()` won't retrieve the DOM element. Consider finding the parent of both elements, and then get your element with `find()`.
2. You still have to parse the value to an int.

---

### Why an int and not a string?

The result of two string comparison is not what you need : the string comparison is going to compare each character of both string, one by one, and at the end determine the result of your comparison.

Example :

If *'10'* and *'8'* are compared, then when it will compare the two string, it will compare both it will compare *'1'* and *'8'*, and then *'0'* and *nuts*.

At that moment, *'1'* will be closer to the start of the alphabet than *'8'*, and then your test will return false, whatever the following character are.

See [this article](http://javascript.about.com/od/decisionmaking/a/des02.htm) for further details.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/eYWwy/) available.

Comment: This is a great solution.  I very much appreciate your feedback!  Thank you